# Inequality between standardized cumulants: $\rho_4\geq\rho_3^2-2$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, reference-request, cumulants

Suppose that $X$ is a random varible with moments $\mu_1'$, $\mu_2'$, $\mu_3'$, $\mu_4'$ and central moments $\mu_1=0$, $\mu_2=\text{Var}(X)$, $\mu_3$ and $\mu_4$. Define the cumulants
\begin{aligned}
k_1&=\mu_1',\\
k_2&=\mu_2'-(\mu_1')^2=\mu_2,\\
k_3&=\mu_3'-3\mu_1'\mu_2'+2(\mu_1')^3=\mu_3,\\
k_4&=\mu_4'-4\mu_1'\mu_3-3(\mu_2')^2+12(\mu_1')^2\mu_2'-6(\mu_1')^4=\mu_4-3\mu_2^2,
\end{aligned}
and standardized cumulants $\rho_r=\frac{k_r}{k_2^{r/2}}$. My text mentions the following inequality in passing
$$
\rho_4\geq\rho_3^2-2.
$$
I can prove this particular one but the text has a few others. What is a **source of statements and proofs** for similar inequalities?

---

**My proof** (please share if you have a different one): the required inequality is equivalent to 
$$
\frac{k_4}{k_2^2}\geq\frac{k_3^2}{k_2^3}-2\iff k_2k_4\geq k_3^2-2k_2^3.
$$
Then I express $k$'s in terms of the $\mu$'s to rewrite the inequality as
$$
k_2k_4\geq k_3^2-2k_2^3\iff\mu_2(\mu_4-3\mu_2^2)\geq\mu_3^2-3\mu_2^3\iff\mu_2\mu_4\geq\mu_3^2.
$$
But the last inequality is true thanks to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\mu_3^2=E[(X-\mu_1')(X-\mu_1')^2]^2\leq E[(X-\mu_1')^2]E[(X-\mu_1')^4]=\mu_2\mu_4.
$$

Comment: The following paper derives inequalities of the type you are interested in: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01043479

Comment: This goes back to the 19th century.  An introduction to part of that literature is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/512862/919.